# Identifying program which created tab file

Tags: geotiff-tiff

How do I identify the format or the program which created following geo tiff and tab files?

I am trying to update map images in our custom program which uses following tab format and tiff files and no way to contact original developer as he is nowhere to be found.

### Following is content of one of the tab files:

```
!table
!version 300 
!charset WindowsLatin1


Definition Table   
File "1000001.TIF"   
Type "RASTER"   
(524448,182304) (0,6912) Label "Pt 1", 
(524448,192672) (0,0) Label "Pt 2",    
(534816,192672) (6912,0) Label "Pt 3",  
(534816,182304) (6912,6912) Label "Pt 4"  
CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 79, "m", -2, 49, 0.9996012717, 400000, -100000  
Units "m"
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not agree with [@NathanW's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24882/115).

`!version 300` can give us that it is a MapInfo tab file but it doesnt give us `which program use for creating this tab file.`

so when you convert your shp data to tab file in globalmapper it also create `!version 300` but no info about which program is used.

you can find more info [here](http://georezo.net/jparis/mb_r/down/TAB%20file%20format.zip). The following info was taken from [Jacques Paris](http://georezo.net/jparis/) experience.

**Structure of Tab File Format**

> Identified versions
>
> The version seems to be set automatically by MI to the minimum
> compatible with the table.
>
> 300     basic, most commonly used
>
> 400     when Metadata is present (*)
>
> 410     for MDB ACCESS files
>
> 450     for XLS files
>
> 500     for MIG files
>
> ```
>     (*) an assumption based on the appearance of Metadata functions in MB language version 4
>
>     Note: there may be different versions associated with the raster formats; new ones may have been included since the version 3
> ```
>
> and that may have some effect on the version number. I do not have
> enough examples to verify all the formats recognized by MI in version
> 6.0: BIL, TIF, BMP, GIF, TGA, JPG, PCX. This list according to the help file does not include GRC that shows up in the "open file"
> requester and that may have been abandoned since version 3.
>
> Format structure
>
> header:
>
> !table required
>
> !version 300 required, variable, controlled by MI
>
> !charset WindowsLatin1 required, variable, depending on user's choice
>
> body:
>
> ```
> commands:
>
> These are MapBasic commands similar to those present in a WOR.
>
> They are executed sequentially and before the next segment (table definition) is read. They cannot thus be applied to the table defined
> ```
>
> later on.
>
> ```
> table definition:
>
> Variations depending on the nature of the nature. See "Detailed table definitions"
>
> metadata:
>
> Metadata commands. They can be added to any tab file. They can be retrieved only if an application does it explicitly (as MI with the
> ```
>
> interpolator definition of a MIG file; see "Detailed table
> definitions")
>
> The sequence of these 3 blocks must be respected but they may not all
> be present. The most frequent case calls only for table definition;
> that block can be sometimes followed by metadata (always, in a MIG
> file). There are rare examples of tabs with only a command block (see
> "Special examples"). Nothing stops us from imagining commands and
> table definition, and, why not, metadata, in the same TAB file.

Answer (score 0):

That is a MapInfo tab file that is used to register a raster image.

The `!version 300` tells you it was created with a MapInfo version 3, although MapInfo will try and save using the oldest version file it can even when using a new version.  So MapInfo 11 can still save version 3 files if nothing in the file is using a version 10 feature.